# How to do BLASTP for short sequences (<20 aa) effectively?

Tags: sequence-alignment, blast, covid-19, sequence-homology, blastp

I am trying to find sequence homology between viral sequences and my protein of interest. I have the sequences of their epitopes which varies from 5 to 500 amino acids long. For shorter sequences, it is recommended to use `blastp-short` but I am confused until which length it is okay to run `blastp`?

For shorter sequences, what are the parameters needs to be added for effective results?

`blastp -task blastp-short -query POI.fasta -db virus.fasta -out output.txt -outfmt 6 -evalue 20000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increase the `-evalue 10` default option to a higher value because this value it's adjusted to the sequence database size. Check this table, maybe this can help you to decide which parameters are the best option for you.

```
    OPTION      TASK          DEFAUL    DESCRIPTION
    word_size   blastp        3         Word size of initial match.
    word_size   blastp-short  2         Word size of initial match.
    gapopen     blastp        1         Cost to open a gap.
    gapopen     blastp-short  9         Cost to open a gap.
    gapextend   blastp        1         Cost to extend a gap.
    gapextend   blastp-short  1         Cost to extend a gap.
    matrix      blastp        BLOSUM62  Scoring matrix name.
    matrix      blastp-short  PAM30     Scoring matrix name.
    threshold   blastp        11        Minimum score to add a word to the BLAST lookup table.
    threshold   blastp-short  16        Minimum score to add a word to the BLAST lookup table.
    window_size blastp        40        Multiple hits window size, use 0 to specify 1-hit algorithm.
    window_size blastp-short  15        Multiple hits window size, use 0 to specify 1-hit algorithm.
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain what is the meaning of `word_size` and `window_size` in the parameters?

Comment: The `word_size` parameter is used in the initial search when BLAST makes a table of all possible "words" present in the query sequence. This first search is not only for identical "words" but for all "words" that would yield an alignment with a score above a threshold, with this step, BLASTp increases speed at the expense of only a small loss in sensitivity by only trying to extend a "hit" if there is a second "hit" within a certain `window_size`.

Comment: How does `word_size` effects my BLASTp result? If I want to find 5 or 6 amino acid match at least then increasing `word_size` to 5 or 6 will help? It means it will try to find 5 or 6 amino acids initial match?